# Reviews - No code first-question, with a to-do list to be accomplished

Tags: discussion, review-queues, first-questions

While doing my daily reviews, I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/34456299). It seemed to me some sort of *"Please code something for me, I will not write anything"*. I chose to share a feedback (this is a user with >1K rep in many other communities), but no luck. After some edits and many comments, the author insists he is right.
Should this type of questions quickly be flagged in some way? Or in the end, is he right?

Comment: This seems to need "more focus". The question cites many separate tasks that need to be done.

Comment: No, he's not right. If he really wants to ask multiple questions, he simply should post multiple question. But as MisterMiyagi said, it need more focus. You simply have to flag it :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The lack of code is a red herring. Only debugging questions *need* a MRE, for everything else code *can* be used to clarify the question.

---

The issue is that the question presents *multiple* tasks without focusing on *one specific* problem about this:

> On load: Create timer Create variable to contain path to target folder
> create an array to contain the file name of each image in the target
> folder
>
> Loop For every file in the target folder add the name to the array
> loop until there are no more files in the folder that haven't been
> indexed end loop
>
> Set timer interval to 30 seconds.
>
> On timer interval call function
>
> For every timer interval set the wallpaper on screen number 2 to be
> the target file path + the file name held in the current array index.
> Increment the array index by one
>
> reset timer to zero
>
> loop until manually terminated.

The recent edits do not change that. There is an indication that the OP *might* know how to do *some* of the tasks and struggles to combine them, but it is not spelled out *which* parts those are and what the specific problem in combining them is. The code shown is largely unrelated (showing how to *watch* a directory of files) so it does not restrict the scope either.

Vote to close or flag as "needs improvement" -> "needs more focus".

Comment: I have no qualms close voting the null program as a debugging problem with no [mre].

Comment: @philipxy You should have as it isn't a debugging problem.

Comment: The null program is what they gave & it doesn't do what they want. So it is a debugging problem/question.

Comment: @philipxy Unless they ask a debugging question, it is not a debugging question. Re-interpreting questions like that just because it "allows" to close vote is extremely harmful. A how-to question with code sample is perfectly valid and does *not* automatically chameleon-turn it into a debugging question. Demanding an MRE for things that do not need one severely limits the reusability of questions.

Comment: Ok, thanks for guiding me. Now I have more details to handle such questions :)

Comment: Next to "*the*" Issue (Singular) is that the Wording in the quoted '*Outline*' Section is hardly comprehensible, with hardly any Punctuation (3 dots + 1 colon, that's all for 8 paragraphs...!!), some random words with a Capital "in the middle", that sentence for example doesn't make any sense to me: "*Create timer Create variable to contain path to target folder create an array to contain the file name of each image in the target folder*" (Syntax/Grammar/Punctuation/Capitalization/+ missing words I suppose...)

Comment: @philipxy in that framework, if the null program is what they tried and what they want to "debug", then they perfectly well have a MRE. Copying and pasting the null program will reliably result in nothing happening, which differs from the described desired result. That's certainly reproducible and trivially minimal.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The asker's justification basically boiled down to: "I want a wallpaper management application. Here's a random piece of code I found on the internet. Modifying code is on topic, so why won't people modify that and write the entire program for me?"

Comment: @BoogaRoo Even if they did that (they did not – the code was added later) by itself that still would not be a reason to close. If someone would manage to formulate a good question by selecting code and prose snippets randomly, that would be fine. *This question is not good*, there is no need to contrive close reasons based on the asker's motivation or justification.

Comment: @BoogaRoo sure; that's *blatantly* Needs More Focus. We don't need to reinterpret that as a debugging question; we don't need to expect a MRE; and we don't need the "Needs Debugging Details" close reason. We already have a textbook close reason.